# All off with join if includes if and only if query does not work with Rails and Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

What I want is to query for all media that only has "fra" language associated through the `habtm` association. Currently, this query returns `Media` instances that include "fra", so e.g. ["fra", "eng"]. I use Postgres.

So, (1) I want to find the media that has exactly the language 'x' and no other, (2) find the media that has exactly the languages 'x' and 'y', (3) find the media that has exactly the languages 'x', 'y' and 'z' etc.

```rb
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :audio_language_records, :join_table => "audio_languages_media", :class_name => "Language"
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :code
end
```

I have tried this, but it returns all media that includes "fra", but not only "fra"

```
Media.joins(:audio_language_records).where("languages.code = ? AND languages.code != ?", "fra", "eng")
```

The following does not work as intended and returns the same result

```
Media.joins(:audio_language_records).where("languages.code IN (?) AND languages.code NOT IN (?)", ["fra"], ["eng"])
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the SQL that is generated when you run your queries.

Comment: Are you sure `languages.code = ? AND languages.code != ?` works with MySQL?

Comment: @rocket, SQL from the first query `"SELECT "media".* FROM "media" INNER JOIN "audio_languages_media" ON "audio_languages_media"."media_id" = "media"."id" INNER JOIN "languages" ON "languages"."id" = "audio_languages_media"."language_id" WHERE (languages.code = 'fra' AND languages.code != 'eng')"`

Comment: @mu I am not sure if it works in MySQL.

Comment: "what I am trying below used to work with MySQL" suggests otherwise and I don't see how it could possibly work in MySQL. Remember that a WHERE clause is evaluated row-by-row so `c = ? and c != ?` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @mu I removed the remark about MySQL. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to find the Media for which there exists a language.code of 'eng' but no entries in the join table for the same media_id but a different language_id.

```
SELECT * FROM media m1
  JOIN audio_languages_media alm1 ON alm1.media_id = m1.id
  JOIN languages l1 ON alm1.language_id = l1.id 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM audio_languages_media alm2
    WHERE alm1.language_id != alm2.language_id
    AND alm1.media_id = alm2.media_id
  )
  AND l1.code = 'eng';
```

Let us know if this is the right db query so we can help with the AREL.

Edit: Query for when you want to find a media that is in at least 'eng' and 'fra'

```
SELECT * FROM media m1
  WHERE(
    SELECT count(*) FROM audio_languages_media alm2
    JOIN languages l2 ON alm2.language_id = l2.id
    WHERE l2.code in ('eng','fra')
    AND alm2.media_id = m1.id
  ) > 1;
```

Edit: Add @chinshr's query

If you want media that has only exactly 'eng' and 'fra'

```
SELECT * FROM media m1
  WHERE(
    SELECT count(*) FROM audio_languages_media alm2
    JOIN languages l2 ON alm2.language_id = l2.id
    WHERE l2.code IN ('eng','fra')
    AND alm2.media_id = m1.id
    AND (
      SELECT count(*) FROM audio_languages_media alm2 
      WHERE alm2.media_id = media.id
    ) = 2
  ) = 2;
```

This query can be tweaked for more or less languages by adding/removing from the IN array, and adjusting the count at the end to be equal to the number of elements in the IN array.

For this to work reliably, you must have a unique index on audio_languages_media(media_id, language_id);

Comment: Thanks @cmaitchison, it works great for one language e.g. "eng", but it breaks when you want to query for all of "eng" and "fra" to return all media with both of those languages and changing the last part of the query to AND l1.code = "eng" AND l1.code = "fra"

Comment: Ok, thats a different query, let me edit my answer and add that one.

Comment: You recommend to use the first query for one language and the seconds query for multiple? or can the second query be customized to support >= 1 languages? Parameterizing the >0, >1, >2 depending on how many languages are passed in doesn't work.

Comment: Correct, the two questions you are asking are fundamentally different, if I understand them correctly.

Comment: 1.  Find the Media for which there exists a language.code of 'eng' but no entries in the join table for the same media_id but a different language_id.

Comment: 2. Find the media that has as least the languages 'x' and 'y'

Comment: These questions are fundamentally different when translated to SQL, so two different queries are required.

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding the 2nd case, and the question is actually:  Find the media that has exactly the languages 'x' and 'y' and no others?

Comment: Correct, this one, find the media that has exactly the language 'x' and no other, find the media that has exactly the languages 'x' and 'y' and no others, etc.

Comment: Your query is not quite working, yet. Consider example M1 ('fra'), M2 ('ger', 'chn'), M3 ('ger', 'chn', 'jap'), for query ['ger', 'chn'] your query returns M2 and M3, where it should only return M2. I have fixed it by adding ...AND (SELECT count(*) FROM audio_languages_media alm3 WHERE alm3.media_id = media.id) = 2... to the subquery. Now it works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only have one value per row so every value that is "fra" can't be "eng" or any other thing. You're gonna have to check two rows. It can be done in SQL like this for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM languages t1
LEFT JOIN languages t2
    ON t1.id=t2.id AND t2.code="eng"
WHERE t1.code="fra" AND t2.code IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, though we want to return the media, not the languages.

Comment: @chinshr And you want to do it in ruby, I only wrote why your query can't work and how to deal with that part of it.

Comment: Yes, I want to do it in ActiveRecord.

Comment: yes, preferably in AR, but the query is the essential part, translation to AR is less of the issue. Which part would I have to replace in my query?

Comment: Works well for one language, like: Media.
      joins("JOIN audio_languages_media alm1 ON alm1.media_id = media.id").
      joins("JOIN languages l1 ON alm1.language_id = l1.id").
      joins("LEFT JOIN languages l2 ON l1.id = l2.id AND l2.code != 'fra'").
      where("l1.code = ? AND l2.code IS NULL", "fra")